# unnecessary MySQL port forwording for WAN connection

Tags: mysql, port-forwarding

I have an application that have MySQL as back-end database server,but while I was scanning open ports using `nmap`, I recognized that the MySQL port had been forwarded to be accessed over a WAN connection.  I didn't want it to be forwarded.

Is there any procedures to prevent WAN port forwarding?

I have tried to block it using windows firewall but it blocked LAN *and* WAN connections.

Comment: It sounds like that computer might be configured as a DMZ host.  That's when all traffic will be forwarded to it.  Since you didn't provide any specifics (OS version, type of router, the configuration on your router, what specifically you've tried to block in the firewall) you won't get much help here.

Comment: *"the MySQL port had been forwarded"* ...specifically, please explain: forwarded by what device?